# Ansible: Run 1 task on 1 host under several users

Tags: ansible

I have 1 VM, there are several applications on it. Each app is working under it's own user.

```
host:
– host1
users:
– app1
– app2
```

They have similar configuration files, the difference is in names and some sensitive data. So, is there any way to run 1 task for several users on 1 host with ansible in parallel.

smth like this.

**inventory:**

```
[webservers:children]
app1
app2

[app1]
127.0.0.1
[app2]
127.0.0.1
```

**group_vars/app1/vars.yml:**

```
---
app_user: app1
var2: value
```

**group_vars/app2/vars.yml:**

```
---
app_user: app2
var2: value
```

**tasks/test.yml:**

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: Copy config
    become: true
    become_user: {{ app_user }}
    template: ....
```

So invoking task in this way, works only with first app. I understand that I can make a playbook for every app_user or write one playbook with sequence of tasks for each app_user, but is there a way how to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work, because:

> Within any section, redefining a var will overwrite the previous instance. If multiple groups have the same variable, the last one loaded wins. If you define a variable twice in a play’s vars: section, the 2nd one wins.

[Ansible doc: playbooks_variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

In my understanding of the documentation `app_user` under `group_vars/app2/vars.yml` should overwrite `app_user` under `group_vars/app1/vars.yml`.

What should work would be to call each hostgroup in a separate play:

```
---
- hosts: app1
  tasks:
  - name: Copy config
    become: true
    become_user: {{ app_user }}
    template: ....

- hosts: app2
  tasks:
  - name: Copy config
    become: true
    become_user: {{ app_user }}
    template: ....
```

Also:

It is not necessary or a good practise to use becom_user for a `template` task. Use the template module like this:

```
---
- hosts: app1
  tasks:
  - name: Copy config
    template:
      src: template.j2
      dest: /some/remote/path
      owner: "{{ app_user }}"
      group: "{{ app_user }}"
      mode: 0755
```

Comment: hmm, i didn't think in that way))) thank you! I can put all configs under root and then change owner to app_user. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a role and call it multiple times giving there different variables (users).

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - common
    - { role: foo_app_instance, dir: '/opt/a',  app_port: 5000 }
    - { role: foo_app_instance, dir: '/opt/b',  app_port: 5001 }
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#passing-different-parameters).
In this way you will reuse your code (if tasks are really similar).

Comment: yes, that's also a good idea. But it will not run roles in parallel. I think will use the solution in next comment. Put configs under root account, then change permissions for each user and then run restart commands separately.